# configure: error: openwsman is required for the Hyper-V driver

Tags: hyper-v, libvirt

I am trying to install libvirt-3.5.0 on my ubuntu machine. When I tried to configure libvirt with hyperv, xen and esxi driver using the following command:

```
./configure --prefix=/usr --localstatedir=/var --sysconfdir=/etc --with-esx=yes --with-xen=yes --with-hyperv=yes
```

Then I got the following error:

```
configure: error: openwsman is required for the Hyper-V driver
```

I have installed openwsman but why libvirt is unable to find openwsman. What is the solution for this...